# Spoiled food or Ill food

Tags: meaning

Are "spoiled food" and "ill food" the same thing? I think the concept ***ill food*** is archaic, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you think "ill food" is archaic, what made you  believe it?

Comment: It does appear in Gulliver's travels  "Twelve of our crew were dead by immoderate labour and ill food".  It probably hasn't been used much since 1800.

Comment: Thanks James K, that's it

Comment: @ben_mb that is not common in modern English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this concerns a phrase from a book that was not written in modern English.  Ngrams only shows hits for "ill food workers" (the workers are ill not the food" or OCR misreading of the roman digit III Food ...

Comment: James K, the subject matter is still English, even if it is archaic

Comment: @ben_mb do u think it's potentially helpful for modern English learners ?

Comment: @Sam not potentially, but may be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Ill' as an adjective, used that way ('harmful') is severely archaic or obsolete; the most recent quotation in the Oxford English Dictionary is from *Gulliver's Travels*, and dated 1726.

> b.A.3.b Unwholesome, injurious to health. Obs.
>
> c 1470 Henry Wallace ii. 155 *Ill meyt and drynk thai gert on till
> hym giff.*
>
> 1640 Quarles Enchirid. iv. 55 *Ill diet may hasten them
> unto their journey's end.*
>
> 1726 Swift Gulliver i. i, *Dead by
> immoderate labour and ill food*.

Comment: I have been known to say that breaking a mirror is an 'ill omen', but I am fond of old-fashioned language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall ever hearing someone say "ill food".

I see two posters saying it is used in Gulliver's Travels, which I read many years ago, so okay, I guess I've read it, but I don't remember it. Perhaps it was a common phrase when that book was written, but it certainly isn't today.

Comment: ill adjective (BAD) is common enough but mainly in fixed expressions like ill health, ill omen, etc. Cambridge Dictionary calls it 'formal or literary'.

Comment: And there's **ill-gotten gains**.

Comment: @TimR - yes, but I think that's an adverbial use. Ill-met, ill-matched, ill-founded, etc.

Comment: to be ill.  Used a lot. Especially in BrE. Whereas AmE say sick. sick, the verb,  in BrE means to throw up.

Comment: "Ill at ease". "Ill at these numbers" However it's unusual as an adjective in modern English, "spoiled" (by means of something that's happened) or "unfit for human consumption" (by means of what's in it) would be more common.

Comment: It's certainly true that "ill" is an adjective. Literally, as in, "I am feeling ill today". Metaphorically, as in "ill-gotten gains" But the question wasn't, "Is 'ill' an adjective?", but whether "ill food" is a term that native speakers use. And the answer to that is "no".